# Sum of a summation in mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following query, in the top select statement `(sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt))` works well but in the union I want to find the total of `(sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt))` query from the top select statement However my solution seems to be off I need some help please

```
select 
(sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt)),


from receipt_history l

     UNION

select 
SUM(sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt)),


from receipt_history l
```

THIS is what the initial table looks like

```
id  app_ln_amnt
1   2
1   2
1   2
1   2
2   5
3   7
4   9


id  app_ln_amnt
1   2
2   5
3   7
4   9
total   23
```

Now my table looks like the second one but the `total is 29` and im trying to get it to be `23`

Comment: Just to make sure, you want the total of `(sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt))`?

Comment: yes the total of (sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt))

Comment: Your difference from the 23 to 29 is due to the duplicates of ID = 1.  Why does this ID have 4 entries where the others only 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery rather than a union

```
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM 
  (select 
  (sum(l.app_ln_amnt)/count(l.app_ln_amnt)) AS value
  from receipt_history l ) t
```

Comment: How about finding the sum of the average, example select avg(app_loan_amnt) from receipt_history
union 
select sum(avg(app_ln_amnt)) i know the last union statement is incorrect but how would I do that

Comment: The query I posted would return the sum of the average. The sub query calculates all of the averages, and then the outer query sums all of those averages.